# Setting variables with executing a command with exec

Tags: bash, syntax, exec

You can set a variable for a single command like this:

```
MY_VARIABLE=my_value ./my_script.sh
```

You can hand off to another script like this:

```
exec ./my_script.sh
```

But when I try to do both like this:

```
exec MY_VARIABLE=my_value ./my_script.sh
```

I get an error:

```
exec: MY_VARIABLE=my_value: not found
```

Why is that?
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to use `env` to specify the environment variable:

```
exec env MY_VARIABLE=my_value ./my_script.sh
```

If you want your script to start with an empty environment or with only the specified variables, use the `-i` option.

From `man env`:

```
   env - run a program in a modified environment
```

Comment: How to add multiple env vars?

Comment: I know it's old, but just to answer @maxgalbu question: `exec env VAR1=value env VAR2=value2 ./my_script.sh`

Answer (score 18):

In bash, you can set environment variables for a command by putting the assignments at the beginning of the command. This works the same for `exec` as any other command, so you write:

```
MYVARIABLE=my_value exec ./my_script.sh
```

Comment: The nice thing about 'exec env' is that you can use it on a variable that may or may not set shell variables. for example if I have a script which does some setup for an arbitrary command, I could end it with `exec env "$@"` and it will work whether or not "$@" sets variables. To use this solution, I'd have to parse and split up the arguments in "$@".